# How to set directory of the URL as index param in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get the last directory name in a URL and send to a subfolder index.php as a parameter.

```
e.g.

mydomain.com/mysubfolder/hi
to
mydomain.com/mysubfolder/?p=hi
```

Next code in the .htaccess file do the redirect to the index.php without change the URL but the param is not sent.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Note: The .htaccess is in "mysubfolder" not in the root.

I was reading others threads but none works.

Any idea why and how to solved it? **Thanks**

**EDIT:**

The problem is that I am trying to get the params with Javascript in the index.php file:

```
//Get URL Params
const queryString = window.location.search
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
const URL_p = urlParams.get('p')
```

I can´t understand why JS doesn't catch the .htaccess parameters ($1 $2 etc..) but yes is geting parameters from {QUERY_STRING} .htaccess

It works correctly if I get the param with PHP Request:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST[p] ; ?>
```

Comment: you're quite doing the opposite!

Comment: @anubhava error "The rule was not met" : https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/?share=3cfc39e5-69f1-4f18-8efe-ce6b7932993a

Comment: @OMiShah Could you write how do it correctly? :)

Answer (score 1):

To include subfolder, you would need regex with 2 variables,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)$ $1/index.php?p=$2
```

`^(.*?)` - will contain your first immediate subfolder in variable `$1`

`/(.*?)$` - anything after the subfolder will be in variable `$2`

Answer (score 0):

Change your RegEx to match only second part of URL, not whole URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*?)$ index.php?p=$1
```

[.htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=646c0d9a-576d-4edd-a752-8be2685cc86e)

Comment: With that line,  404 is returned if no final slash. If final slash nothing happend

Comment: 404 is returned if no final slash.( I think because "my-subfolder" is not catched in the output) Any idea how to include subfolder in the new URL? Thanks